# How can I add a dynamic value to the Contact Form 7 Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

How can I add a dynamic value to Contact Form 7 without using an extra plugin. I need to display the Post title in the emails sent.

I am using the example in the Contact Form 7 docs [here](https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/), but the `clock` tag only shows in the form page and not in the emails sent.

I don't know if there is something missing, or if I should add anything else to make this work?

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_form_tag_clock' );

function custom_add_form_tag_clock() {
   wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'clock', 'custom_clock_form_tag_handler' ); // "clock" is the type of the form-tag
}

function custom_clock_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
   return date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ) );
}
```

Comment: Is the post title somewhere on the page? Then you could just include a hidden input field which you could fill with javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in the contact form 7 documentation https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

I've added the special mail tag `[_post_title]` in the message body that is sent by contact form 7, and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin build exactly for that. https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/  Please check to see if it fits your needs!

Comment: What if i don't want to use an extra plugin for that?